# OutputCodeClassifier object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, multiclass-classification

I am working with m*ulticlass classifier*, so during calling `predicat_proba()` i am facing with such error:

```
AttributeError: 'OutputCodeClassifier' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

I checked documentation of `scikit-learn` (multioutput-classifier) that support `predict_proba()` but when I am calling this method I am facing with above error that I have shown.

I tried this code:

```
X_train_logregr, X_test_logregr, y_train_logregr, y_test_logregr = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size = 0.3, random_state=42)

scaler_logregr = StandardScaler() X_train_scaled_logregr = scaler_logregr.fit_transform(X_train_logregr)

X_test_scaled_logregr = scaler_logregr.transform(X_test_logregr)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
output = OutputCodeClassifier(logreg)
output.fit(X_train_scaled_logregr, y_train_logregr)
y_pred = output.predict(X_test_scaled_logregr)

y_pred_proba = output.predict_proba(X_test_scaled_logregr)
```

but when i am running it shows this error:

```
AttributeError: 'OutputCodeClassifier' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

Comment: The documentation does not show that this method exists in OutputCodeClassifier: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OutputCodeClassifier.html

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, i am using version 1.0.2: https://scikit-learn.org/1.0/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html?highlight=multioutput#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier

Answer (score 0):

`OutputCodeClassifier()` with the default settings fits 1.5x number of classes binary classifiers, assigns Hamming codes to classes, then selects the nearest class when doing prediction. As you can see, interpreting this in a probabilistic way is not so trivial! Thus, `predict_proba()` method is not provided.

You can still try a sort of a hacky workaround to access the individual estimators and compare those to `output.code_book_` entries.:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import _predict_binary
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

# this is what predict() method does internally, except predict() ends with argmin:
predictions = np.array([_predict_binary(e, X_test) for e in output.estimators_]).T
probs = 1 - euclidean_distances(predictions, output.code_book_)
```

Those even sum to 1 in the simple cases.